# Flutter - Image object from Codec object

Tags: image, flutter, dart, codec

The Image class documentation states

"To obtain an Image object, use instantiateImageCodec."

The instantiateImageCodec documentation states

"Instantiates an image codec Codec object."

From that it would be reasonable to assume that Codec is a sub-class of Image... Nope! I can't find information anywhere about how to get from a Codec object to an Image object.

What is the functionality that needs to go into my convert function below?

```
Image convert(Codec c){
    ...
}
```

The code I'm trying to use this in is as follows:

```
static Future<Image> convertBytesToImage(List<int> bytes){
    Uint8List list = Uint8List(bytes.length);
    list.setAll(0, bytes);
    Future<Codec> codec = instantiateImageCodec(list);

    // Do something here so that I can return as Future<Image>
}
```

Comment: @pskink - I've edited the question to include some context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter has multiple classes named `Image`.  Do you actually want a `dart:ui` `Image` object?  If you want an `ImageProvider` for use with an `Image` *widget*, you can use [`MemoryImage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/MemoryImage-class.html) (to get an `ImageProvider`) or [`Image.memory`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Image/Image.memory.html) (to go directly to a widget).

If you do need to use to use `dart:ui`'s `Image`, then you can use `(await codec.getNextFrame()).image`.

Comment: MemoryImage was the way to go. Everything is working as expected now. Thanks.